# Laravel 5.8 + FullCalendar + Popover: Attempting to replicate demo is failing with popover error

Tags: php, laravel, fullcalendar, popover, fullcalendar-2

In my application, I am trying to use FullCalendar to display events.  Specifically, I'm trying to replicate the [demo example](https://codepen.io/IsmiKin/pen/WbOeGw) they provide.

I am making use of maddHatter\laravel-fullcalendar

My Laravel/PHP code in a blade template to generate the calendar is as follows:

```
            $cal_events = [];
            foreach ($events as $key => $value) {
                $cal_events[] = Calendar::event(
                    $value->eventName,
                    false,
                    new \DateTime($value->eventStartDate),
                    new \DateTime($value->eventEndDate),
                    $value->eventID,
                    // Add color
                    [
                        'color' => '#0000FF',
                        'textColor' => '#FFFFFF',
                        'url' => env('APP_URL')."/events/$value->slug",
                        'description' => $value->eventDescription,
                    ]
                );
            }

            $calendar = Calendar::addEvents($cal_events)
            ->setCallbacks([
                'eventRender' => 'function(event, element) {
                    element.popover({
                        container: "body",
                        html: true,
                        placement: "top",
                        trigger: "hover",
                        title: "Random Title",
                        content: "Some Content"
                    });
                 }'
            ]);

<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <b>{!! $header !!} </b>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body" >
            {!! $calendar->calendar() !!}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tooltip.js/dist/umd/tooltip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.7/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
{!! $calendar->script() !!}
```

I can get the calendar to display with my events just fine when I do not have the ->setCallBacks() portion above.

Adding it in results in the following error when looking at the console in Chrome:

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: element.popover is not a function
at Object.eventRender (1:formatted:83)
at me.U [as trigger] (fullcalendar.min.js:6)
at t.constructor.trigger (fullcalendar.min.js:8)
at t.constructor.resolveEventEl (fullcalendar.min.js:8)
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (fullcalendar.min.js:7)
at Function.each (VM2577 jquery.min.js:2)
at r.fn.init.each (VM2577 jquery.min.js:2)
at t.constructor.renderFgSegEls (fullcalendar.min.js:7)
at t.constructor.renderFgSegs (fullcalendar.min.js:7)
at t.constructor.renderEvents (fullcalendar.min.js:7)
```

What am I missing?

If there is anything else you need to know, ask and I will provide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CodePen demo you've linked to includes Bootstrap's JavaScript and CSS files, which [provide the popover functionality](https://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.0.3/docs/javascript/#popovers). Your version doesn't, from what you've shown.

Check what's included in the CodePen (it's in the Settings area) and make sure you've got the same or very similar version of Bootstrap available to your page.

Comment: P.S. you're using a very old, unsupported version of fullCalendar there - v5 is about to be released. It's a long time since v2 had any enhancements or bug fixes. I know you used that package to provide Laravel integration but actually integrating fullCalendar into an MVC-style app such as Laravel is quite simple - all you really need is a view with the correct javascript and css included, and an action method which returns JSON (to provide a feed of events). The rest of it doesn't rely on the server-side at all. So you could ditch that package and use the latest fullCalendar quite easily.